# How to write a plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

How can I start writing a plugin for [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)?

I've looked for documentation, but unfortunately there is very little or it's poor, so what articles can recommended?

Comment: Documentation on writing plugins is anything but poor. If you haven't found any, you just haven't looked.

Comment: @Jesper: unfortunately the docs from eclipse is chaotic, not systematic, although vast.

Comment: For people coming to this later who just want some working code to play with - I've got some skeleton projects at http://joereddington.com/4149/2014/09/24/eclipse-plugins/ with links to the github repos and such...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are some pretty good resources and tutorials on the main Eclipse and IBM's site. One of the best ways is to pick an open source plug-in that has some similar features to what you want to do and start to dissect it.

- *[PDE Does Plug-ins](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-does-plugins/PDE-intro.html)*
- *[Plug-in development 101, Part 1: The fundamentals](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-plugindev1/index.html)*
- *[Eclipse Plugins Exposed, Part 1: A First Glimpse](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/02/09/eclipse.html)*
- *[Developing Eclipse plug-ins](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecplug/)*

Answer (score 23):

Eclipse has a pretty good "[Your First Plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html)" tutorial.  If it is confusing, I'm sure they would greatly appreciate your feedback.  Keep in mind that Eclipse is essentially Java, so if you don't have a good grasp of Java go for general Java tutorials first, and then come back to Eclipse development.

O'Reilly has two good Eclipse Plugin tutorials:

- [Eclipse Plugins Exposed](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/02/09/eclipse.html)
- [Develop Your Own Plugins for Eclipse](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/08/18/eclipseplugins.html)

They not only go through the simple code examples, but give you screen shots of the process since a lot of work is done through wizard type interface windows.

If these aren't helpful, perhaps you could be more specific as to what is difficult to follow.

-Adam

Comment: For what it's worth, the first link has been "retired" (to use their own words) - the new link - http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-does-plugins/PDE-intro.html - the accepted answer has this link

Comment: I wish the official tutorial were updated to reflect what everything is called now.  It was five years old when this question was answered, and now it's a decade out of date.

Comment: The O'Reilly links don't work anymore.

Comment: Try https://web.archive.org/web/20180506194534/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/02/09/eclipse.html and https://web.archive.org/web/20180505090910/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/08/18/eclipseplugins.html - but keep in mind these resources are over a decade old, and may no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The best step-by-step that covers almost every aspect of plugin development is the book "Eclipse: Building Commercial Quality Plugins".

It's available at most book shops and electronically at safari:
http://safari.oreilly.com/9780321574435

Answer (score 1):

I found a great Eclipse plugin tutorial named *[Extending Eclipse - Plug-in Development Tutorial](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-1-what-im-going-to-do/)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very good resource is also to look at the examples that are available via the new Plug-In Project wizard.

Depending on what you want to provide with your plug-in, you can choose from editor plug-ins, view plug-ins, plug-ins that provide a property page (just to name a few) and see how they're built and what extension points they implement.