# How to make a new Eclipse project template?

Tags: eclipse, templates, project-template

I am using a kind of framework where every time I make a new Java project. I have to arrange the files in the appropriate packages and reference the appropriate external [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) libraries. How do I make a new project template like in the New Project dialog under a new folder?

Comment: It looks strange, I could not not find any hint about this relatively simple question. Did you?

Comment: where can i find some example of plugin that make a custom template project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to write an Eclipse plugin for that, and concentrate on New Project Wizard.

Writing Eclipse plugins is covered in Stack Overflow question *[How to write a plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299283)*.

Answer (score 29):

I've just done a bit of research on this for our own nefarious purposes, and found the answer.

You need to create an Eclipse plugin that uses the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` package.  You can define your own category or use an existing one once you find the category ID.  To create a new *project* wizard rather than a new *resource* wizard, you need to set the "project=true".

Also, your plugin must contain a class that implement `org.eclipse.ui.INewWizard`.  Clicking on the class link from the `plugin.xml` editor will do the trick.

That class must do all the work in the `performFinish` override, and must return true to indicate that it actually did its thing and the wizard can close.  This is where you create files, directories, set natures, and so forth.