# How to use an existing Project as a template for a new one with Eclipse (CDT)?

Tags: eclipse, templates, project-management, eclipse-cdt

I'd like to use one of my Projects where everything is configured fine and how it is need to start working as a "template" for creating a new Project within eclipse with CDT.

So that time for configuring and writing a working project can be safed because it was already made somewhere else.

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always right-click the project, choose "copy" and then hit ctrl+v (command+v on mac) to paste a new copy of the project into the workspace, then delete the source files that you don't need, leaving only the project configuration.

Comment: Just that simple? Mhm, ok, it copies SVN storage information also, but this could be changed easily too.

Comment: It's not that simple - certainly now (as of 19th February 2020). Creating a new project defines unique IDs for build configurations. If you copy and paste, you can end up with two projects that have identical (i.e. not unique) IDs. On Eclipse CDT in 2019-09 and 2019-12, doing this can cause issues if you use the "References" tab in "Paths and Symbols" to link specific build configurations together.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas:

1. You can also use File->Export to export the C/C++ project settings, and include those with the project itself (like on a git repo?)
2. You could make your 'perfect' starting project and use that as a git repo. Then, when you want to use it, just clone and disconnect (under the team menu) the template. Finally, you can re-share to a new repo?
3. Save the project as 'read-only' and use it as a starting point (now use Save as..) (Not tested, just an idea)

Finally, if you want to do it right, your going to have to write up a plugin! Yay!

[Good starting point if you choose this route from this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414020/how-to-make-a-new-eclipse-project-template)

[More on making Eclipse plugins (a bit old)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299283/how-to-write-a-plugin-for-eclipse)

Good luck! And let us know if you come up with anything else...