# Eclipse CDT: Automatically Add Header File

Tags: c++, eclipse, header

I'm working through *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*, and it's recommended/necessary to include a particular header file from the author's site, called std_lib_facilities.h. It's kind of a pain, though, to manually add this file to each project source folder whenever I start a new project. Is there some way to have it added to a project folder upon creation?

Answer (score 0):

Here everything is explained [How to use an existing Project as a template for a new one with Eclipse (CDT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243121/how-to-use-an-existing-project-as-a-template-for-a-new-one-with-eclipse-cdt)

Just create a new project in Eclipce C++. It can be "Hello, world" project from CDT templates. Then edit source file, add  #include "std_lib_facilities.h" and add std_lib_facilities.h itself to the folder (for example src folder). Then save everything and do not change it anymore. It will be yout Base project for all future projects.

After that every time you need create another project with std_lib_facilities.h included in ProjectExplorer panel or in C/C++Projects panel press "Copy" and then "Paste". You will be asked for a name of new project and then all files will be copied.

That is it.