# How to bundle an Eclipse project into an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I would like to add a feature to a plugin which I am developing.

This feature, when activated by the user, would create (or prompt and guide) a new project for the user, and this project would have a per-bundled structure. Is this even possible?

If not, what are some alternatives to have an Eclipse plugin setup a specific Eclipse project for a user?

Comment: I think your question has answered yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414020/how-to-make-a-new-eclipse-project-template

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`BasicNewProjectResourceWizard`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/wizards/newresource/BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.html).