# Can i create an android application as template?

Tags: android, templates, implementation

I'm not sure if its the right title but ill explain what i mean.
I'm making more than one android application, but they have the same structure 
sliding menu , list view , about me , costume dialog  with (copy,share,like) 
with some modifications in the styles (colors, backgrounds , fonts , menu strings )

my qustion is : is there any way to use the structure as library or implemntation or anu other way 
insted of coping the same codes in every projects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is to create an `Android library`. Just develop it like a normal application, with `Activities` and `layout`.

Please follow this tutorial to set up your project. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

When you'll create a new project with the given library, all your code will be silently included and you'll get access to your `Activities` and even to your `R` class.

Answer (score 2):

Try **Android studio - Official IDE** for android development. Simple to use.

There is an option to save your project as template. **Tools > Save project as template** [image]

For eclipse I think you need to write plugin https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992150/3020568