# Is there possibility to save project as template in Android Studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to prepare custom Android project template with some classes and dependencies. Accordingly to this answer [Saving project template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885670/2873784), this possibility exists. But I did not found this menu in Android Studio 3.1. How to build Android Project template? Maybe plugin or menu?

Answer (score 0):

That answer is 4 years old.
Create your project, save it and copy it to this directory

```
android-sdk\tools\templates\projects
```

or make your own library

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: Thanks for reply! I added template project to this folder and how than I need to use it? In New Project menu I not see needed template.