# Android Studio custom project template

Tags: android, android-studio, templates

Currently, Android Studio Bumblebee - 2021.1.1 Patch 2.  OP date is 06/11/2022.

When you hit "New Project", there are a number of templates to pick from.  I'd like to create my own template, but have not found a way to do so.  I've found some answers, but they're [old and don't work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973615/is-there-possibility-to-save-project-as-template-in-android-studio-3), or [cryptic and questionably applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623926/how-do-i-create-custom-project-templates-to-android-studio-3-6-or-above), or [apparently for e.g. ACTIVITY templates rather than project templates](https://steewsc.medium.com/template-plugin-for-android-studio-4-1-92dcbc689d39), etc.

Is it possible to create a custom project template for Android Studio 2021.1.1?  For creating a new project?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no documented support for this at this time. That's not to say that you cannot do it, but just bear in mind that your template might need modification at any time, and that there may not be all that much written about it in general.