# Add a custom file to Eclipse/Mule Studio for any NewProjects automatically

Tags: eclipse, mule, mule-studio

To abide some Audit/IT process, we are required to always add File(a TXT & XML file) to our Java projects. Is there a way that I can customize my Eclipse/Mule Studio to add these automatically whenever I create File->New->Mule Project. Because sometimes we miss it and then we need to repackage just because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider also to create a template and upload it to the [Anypoint Exchange](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/), although this is an enterprise feature.

Comment: Thanks @ Victor , we will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

It should be part of your Maven build process to either auto-include these files or die if they are missing. That way, you won't be able to produce invalid Mule applications.

Comment: Thanks @ David for your reply. Currently we don't use build tools like maven. Kindky advise how to achieve this with out maven

Comment: Create a project template for Eclipse, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414020/how-to-make-a-new-eclipse-project-template ? But I **strongly** encourage you to use Maven (or Gradle) to build your Mule application. You wouldn't build Java applications from Eclipse, same applies to Mule applications: use a real build tool and have reproducible automatable builds.

Comment: Thanks @ David for the link.