# How to: Eclipse Plug-in?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have to write a plug-in for Eclipse, but I don't know how to start, is there any one that can help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Google? http://www.google.hu/search?q=eclipse+plugin+tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Please see

- [How to write a plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299283/how-to-write-a-plugin-for-eclipse)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280999/a-good-tutorial-on-building-eclipse-plugins
- http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/
- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html
  -http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting by the official documentation, which is quite good:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/nav/2_0

(read section **Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide**)