# How to make an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a plugin for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299283/how-to-write-a-plugin-for-eclipse)

I want to implement an [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) plugin of my project which is in swt. What is a good tutorial with examples?

I want to run my project in Eclipse when the user clicks my project's (plugin) icon. Which tutorial should I read?

Answer (score 3):

http://vogella.de has [a lot of great articles](http://www.vogella.de/eclipse.html) on this. Start with [Eclipse Plugin Development Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html).

Answer (score 2):

This can be [found by googling *How to write Eclipse plugin*](http://tinyurl.com/422s8ye) (with animation, but requires JavaScript).

Eclipse has a guide for that too, *[Your First Plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html)*.

Comment: he he he, this is great, I didn't know that such a site exists!