# Eclipse - New Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to modify project creation in eclipse. I would like to add my own project creation. For example, when developer selectes File->New->Project, I want my option (i.e, XYZ Java Project) under  to be available. Is this possible ? If yes, i am looking for some direction to begin with ?

Thanks.

Comment: More info: We are developing an application that relies on couple of different jar. Then there are some standard XML files which must be present in all the applications. And there are few more customization. So whenever developer creates new Android project, he/she has to apply all this customization manually. I am looking for a solution where all these can be dome automatically through some scripts, plugin or templates. I am looking for some pointers to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. A robust way to do this is to make an eclipse plugin so that it gets added to the menu. I was just looking into this myself a couple of days ago and this is what I found.

Here are some links:

[O'Reilly](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/08/18/eclipseplugins.html)

Better yet though, let me just show you an answer about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/299316/879485

Answer (score 1):

1. To begin with you need to contribute your own Eclipse Plug in.  Download Eclipse plugin developers IDE  from this [Location](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/europa/winter/eclipse-rcp-europa-winter-win32.zip).
2. You can contribute a Custom Project Wizard  through Extensions.
3. Define your  Project Nature

For reference you can check this example [Create a Custom Project in Eclipse – New Project Wizard: the Behavior](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-4-create-a-custom-project-in-eclipse-new-project-wizard-the-behavior/)

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven you can have a look at [archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).  Maven also has the ability to create Eclipse projects.  With this you should have all the tools necessary to automate whatever project layout you need to have.