# how to check whether a plugin is already installed on eclipse before installing another plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i have 2 plugins named plugin1.jar and plugin2.jar. both are packed as feature projects into separate zipped files(plugin1.zip and plugin2.zip) and are placed on my D drive. now while installing plugin2.zip on eclipse(ofcourse by using the help->install new sofware), plugin2.zip should check whether plugin1 is installed or not. if it is not installed i should get an error asking to install the plugin1 first. in short i want the plugin2 installation to depend on plugin1 installation. user must be able to install plugin2 only when the plugin1 is installed. is there any way to do this. please help.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse - Your First Plug-In](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html) :

> Edit the plugin.xml file so that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
... 
    <requires>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
    </requires>
...
```

> <...>
>  
>   The *requires* element is where you specify all the other plug-ins your plug-in depends on.

See also: [How to write a plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299283/how-to-write-a-plugin-for-eclipse)