# Creating an eclipse plugin without gui: what am I missing?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, code-generation

I'm creating an eclipse plugin using java code generated via a Makefile (yes, I know ant). The final target of my makefile is a zip containing the following structure (I used the plugin for [javacc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-javacc/) as an inspiration):

```
$ unzip -l myplugin_2015.02.16.zip 
Archive:  myplugin_2015.02.16.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  02-16-2015 09:30   feature/
        0  02-16-2015 09:30   feature/myplugin.feature_2015.02.16/
      474  02-16-2015 09:30   feature/myplugin.feature_2015.02.16/feature.xml
        0  02-16-2015 09:30   plugins/
        0  02-16-2015 09:30   plugins/myplugin_2015.02.16/
        0  02-16-2015 09:30   plugins/myplugin_2015.02.16/META-INF/
      527  02-16-2015 09:30   plugins/myplugin_2015.02.16/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
      492  02-16-2015 09:30   plugins/myplugin_2015.02.16/plugin.xml
    23079  02-16-2015 09:30   plugins/myplugin_2015.02.16/idp192.jar
---------                     -------
    24572                     9 files
```

No I'd like to import this zip in eclipse as a new plugin. When I run eclipse->install-new-software->Add->archive it fails with "no software size found for jar:... , do you wish do edit location ?".

I suspect I need to wrap this zip in a site file ? is there a minimal way to create this 'site' archive ? or is there a simplier solution , something missing in my plugin.zip ? Most important, I don't want to use any GUI.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you done it as it was mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299283/how-to-write-a-plugin-for-eclipse) ?

Comment: I've done the equivalent steps using command lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed a few hours later: just moving my *.jar to eclipse/plugin fixed the problem.